# MySQL: How to copy text between columns only if destination is empty?

Tags: mysql

I'm having a database table with two columns - lets call them source and destination, both contain text. Now I'd like to copy the content of the source column into destination column but only at those rows where the destination column is empty. To make things a little more complicated, the destination column should also have a constant string prepanded. How would this SQL statement look like?

Any assistance is welcome,
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET destination = CONCAT('PREFIX', source)
WHERE destination is NULL
;
```